# Is every type realized in a countable model?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Let $p(x)$ be a type of a theory $T$ over the empty set. Is $p$ realized in a countable model of $T$?

I think this is the case, because if add a symbol $\mathring x$ to the language $L$, then the set of formulas $T \cup p(\mathring x)$ is consistent, so it has model $M$, then by Lowenheim-Skolem there is some countable elementary $(L+\mathring x)$-substructure $N$ of $M$ and the reduct of $N$ to $L$ is a model of $T$ realizing $p$. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Your argumemt is correct

Comment: your argument is correct and well reasoned. there is no need to elaborate further.

Comment: It is essential though to assume that the language is countable.

Comment: @MarkKamsma countability not essential in the answer/question. The general fact  (that the argumemt in the OP proves) is: if ∪() is a finitely consistent type, then it is realized in a model of cardinality ≤|∪()|.

Comment: @PrimoPetri Of course the question could be reformulated. But as it is it mentions countability, twice.

Answer (score -1):

Your argument is correct.

It also makes a nice proof by contradiction.

Suppose for contradiction that the 1-type without parameters $p(x)$ was not satisfiable in any countable model,

then $T \cup p(c)$ with $c$ being a fresh constant symbol would be satisfiable in some infinite structure but not in any countably infinite structures.

This contradicts the Löwenheim–Skolem theorem.